# How to give Dockerfile input parameters from docker run command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

```
FROM centos
RUN yum -y update
ENV zk=dx
RUN mkdir  $zk
```

after building image and after  running  fallowing command

```
docker run -it -e zk="hifi" <image ID>
```

I get a directory with name dx but not with hifi

can anyone help me how to set a Dockerfile variable from docker run command

Comment: you can use [build-args](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables-build-arg)

Comment: No,build-args is used to pass argument while building docker I need to pass while running docker

Answer (score 4):

This has behaved this way because:

- The RUN commands in the Dockerfile are executed when the Docker image is **built** (like almost all Dockerfile instructions) - ie. when you run *docker build*
- The *docker run* command runs when the container is **run** from the image.

So when you run *docker run* and set the value to "hifi", the image already exists which has a directory called "dx" in it. The directory creation task has already been performed - updating the environment variable to "hifi" won't change it.

You cannot set a Dockerfile *build* variable at *run* time. The build has already happened.

Incidentally, you're over-writing the value of the zk variable right before you create the directory. If you *did* successfully pass "hifi" into the docker build, it would be over-written and the folder would always be called "dx".

Comment: so how to do pass args from run command to Dockerfile. Actually I have a command in Dockerfile which have some default IP addresses. Now after pulling the image when I run it I will run it by changing to some other IP address ,how to do it

Comment: See the build-args section in the docs. You specify it in the run command, and in the Dockerfile, and then you can use it like an environment variable. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/